# Why tx annotation-driven make a conflict?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

Hi everyone I working with Spring MVC and I have a question.

I have this bean definition for transaction:

```
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="txManager"/>

    <bean id="txManager" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
    </bean>
```

But when I run my application I've got this exception:

> 2019-05-24 18:14:51 DEBUG o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter -
>   Application failed to start due to an exception
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionOverrideException:
>   Invalid bean definition with name
>   'org.springframework.transaction.config.internalTransactionAdvisor'
>   defined in class path resource
>   [org/springframework/transaction/annotation/ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration.class]:
>   Cannot register bean definition [Root bean: class [null]; scope=;
>   abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=3; dependencyCheck=0;
>   autowireCandidate=true; primary=false;
>   factoryBeanName=org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration;
>   factoryMethodName=transactionAdvisor; initMethodName=null;
>   destroyMethodName=(inferred); defined in class path resource
>   [org/springframework/transaction/annotation/ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration.class]]
>   for bean
>   'org.springframework.transaction.config.internalTransactionAdvisor':
>   There is already [Root bean: class
>   [org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.BeanFactoryTransactionAttributeSourceAdvisor];
>   scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0;
>   dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false;
>   factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null;
>   destroyMethodName=null] bound.    at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.registerBeanDefinition(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:897)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitionsForBeanMethod(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:274)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitionsForConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:141)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:117)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:327)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:232)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:275)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:95)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:705)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:531)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:142)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:775)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:316)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1260)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1248)

When I commented tx:annotation-drive everything fine but method with @Transactional annotation didn't work. What am I doing wrong?

My gradle dependencies:

```
compile group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-web', version: '5.1.5.RELEASE'
    compile group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-webmvc', version: '5.1.5.RELEASE'
    compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-web', version: '2.1.3.RELEASE'
compile group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-jdbc', version: '5.1.5.RELEASE'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need to do is enable `Bean Overriding`. As of Spring 2.1 this is disabled by default. You are getting an exception because there is already a bean defined with the same name.

Spring 2.1 release note excerpt: [Release note 2.1 - Bean Overriding](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-2.1-Release-Notes#bean-overriding)

Long story short, you need to add this to your `application.properties` file:

```
spring.main.allow-bean-definition-overriding=true
```

Or in yaml:

```
spring:
   main:
     allow-bean-definition-overriding: true
```

Comment: This is just a workaround but what's the cause of the problem?

Comment: @Pino Its because spring itself has a bean with id "txManager" and OP is creating bean with the same identifier. More information about the error can be found by registering an exception handler: `@ExceptionHandler(value = { BeanDefinitionOverrideException.class })`